Need to run apt-get update twice when using Ubuntu Snapshot Service on arm64
I'm building a Docker image based on Ubuntu Noble, and I'm trying to use the Ubuntu Snapshot Service to ensure consistent reproducible builds.
This works just fine on x86, but was failing when I tried to build on an arm64 machine: apt-get couldn't find any package at all. After much trial-and-error, I discovered that it works if you run apt-get update twice. I'm trying to get to the bottom of why.
Here's my Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:noble

# Makes the output a little nicer
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Required to properly access the snapshot service
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Configure the snapshot
RUN echo "APT::Snapshot \"20240723T151700Z\";" | tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50snapshot

# We need to run apt-get update twice here, but only when we're using a snapshot AND on arm64. Why?!
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install hello -y --no-install-recommends && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN hello

To reproduce, delete the second apt-get update line (since it's a line continuation you can't comment it out), and run:
# Works with only one apt-get update
$ docker buildx build . --platform linux/amd64 --pull --no-cache

# Only works with two apt-get updates
$ docker buildx build . --platform linux/arm64 --pull --no-cache

